# Как сделать выборку элемента по значению специального атрибута?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть ряд элементов с атрибутом start. Значение этого атрибута у всех элементов разный. То есть у одного элемента start-'1', у другого start='2', у третьего start='3'. Как выбрать элемент, у которого атрибут start равен 2?
document.querySelector('#start=2') - что-то вроде этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
document.querySelector('[start=2]')
```